# Python: is this a passing parameter convention?

Tags: python

While I'm going through Python code and seeing functions called, I notice things like

```
functionCall(argument='something')
```

or

```
someclass.functionCall(argument='something')
```

I've played around with it and noticed you have to name that variable with the same name as the one in the scope of the function or class function itself. Is that just a convention (for useful naming) or is there more to it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are just standard [**keyword arguments**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

They are mainly useful when calling functions that usually assume default values, but the user is interested in passing a custom value without affecting the other defaults.
For example:

```
def foo(a='a', b='b', c='c'):
    print a + b + c
```

Then:

```
>>> foo()
'abc'
>>> foo(c='x')  # don't know or care about a and b's value
'abx'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is good to have named arguments as arguments can be specified in any order by using named arguments.

Even required arguments (like object, which has no default value) can be named, and named arguments can appear in any order.

[Also see This](http://davedash.com/2007/12/21/python-named-arguments-pure-genius/)

Python's argument passing mechanisms are extremely flexible.

cons: **too many arguments to a function**. Solutions: split into multiple functions, pass some args together in a dictionary or object.

cons: **bad variable names**. Solution: give variables more descriptive names.

Or remember the correct order .. :)

```
class xyz:
    def __init__ (self, a='1', b='2'):
        print a,b

xyz(b=3,a=4)
xyz(a=5,b=6)

>>4 3
>>5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). Keyword arguments have a couple distinct advantages:

1. They can be specified in any order by the caller.
2. They have default values, which means the caller doesn't have to provide a value for each argument if the defaults are sensible.
3. They can make code more readable. For example, `foo(width=100, height=200)` is easier to understand than `foo(100, 200)`. It is also easier to use, because you don't have to remember whether the function takes width,height or height,width.

Comment: Keyword arguments have little to do with default arguments. It's not that there are two kinds of arguments, positional and keyword, it's that there are two ways to **pass** arguments, either by position or by keyword. A given function's arguments (apart from the `*args` and `**kwargs` catch-alls) can all be provided in either fashion, whether or not they have defaults. It's just that if you want to pass an argument of a function while using the default for an earlier argument, then you must use the keyword style.

Answer (score 1):

these are keyword parameters. They enable you to pass parameters in any order (useful for skipping optional parameters)

Please note though, calling functions that way comes with a little bit of overhead:

```
def test(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c

def t1():
    return test(1,2,3)

def t2():
    return test(a=1, b=2, c=3)

timeit(t1)
    0.23918700218200684
timeit(t2)
    0.2716050148010254
```

Comment: Huh? This (supposed) overhead is completely negligible, and even suggesting this hints at a horrible micro-optimization. Not to mention your benchmark means absolutely nothing.

Comment: Ouch.. Did you not sleep well? 

1. Overhead is never negligible if it's avoidable (ie, just so you don't have to look up the required order of the parameters)

2. How exactly is optimization horrible? 

3. Yes, it means calling a function with named parameters takes a bit longer than just adhering to the order. 

And like I said: it's useful for skipping optional parameters. I just wouldn't use it because it's convenient.